# High ripple in the output

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

We have chosen the [MCP16311](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP16311-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20005255C.pdf) buck converter for 4 V @ 1 A output.
design specifications as below.
Input voltage range: 5 to 20 V (source - USB type C mobile, charging adapter)

- Output Voltage : 4 V
- Output current : 1 A (max)
- LED driving current : 250 mA (LED flashing interval 1 sec on/1 sec off)
- Proximity sensor interval: 1/160 duty interval (peak current 800 mA, and average current is 5 mA)

As at constant load 1 A it has 50 mA ripple which is acceptable to us, but at switching load it has 500-1300 mV of ripple in output and same in input.
Kindly suggest how to overcome this switching load ripples.

Comment: Schematic, layout and datasheet of inductor and capacitors please.

Comment: Did you factor in the dc bias derating for the capacitors?  Anything less than 2 10uF 25V ceramics on the output would be likely to be inadequate.

Comment: How do you measure the ripple